# How to start ssh server on different port?

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh, sshd

I want to start ssh server on port 21 (for one of my local hosts).

OS X Yosemite (10.10.4)

I've changed **/etc/httpd_config** by adding:

```
Port 21
```

Then restarted server:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

But nmap still shows ssh on standart port 22:

```
$ sudo nmap -sS -sV -p 21,22 localhost
Password:

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-08-10 18:00 PDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00020s latency).
PORT   STATE  SERVICE VERSION
21/tcp closed ftp
22/tcp open   ssh     OpenSSH 6.2 (protocol 2.0)

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.20 seconds
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: i'm not familiar with configuring ftp, but to configure the port for ssh, the file you should be editing is sshd_config  That may be /etc/ssh/sshd_config or it may be /etc/sshd_config  (one of the two. check which exists) . And i'm not sure how you're meant to restart the sshd server on your *nix based system, but what you've done doesn't look right for restarting teh server.. the commands look rather long. It should be one short line I think

Comment: 1. restating the ssh agent is not necessary. 2. you can also restart the ssh server via system preference -> shares. 3. (not tested) you should also be able to just `killall sshd` so launchd will restart them.

Comment: @Schwertspize - you are right - unchecking and checking **Remote login** in **system prference => Sharing** is just doing this: `sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist &&
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`  I know all that, but the problem is still there (actually two different machines have the same behavior) - no matter what port I specify in **/etc/sshd_config** ssh server still runs on default port 22. So maybe I have to specify port in more than one place??? I have no clue why specifying `Port 222` is just ignored in my **sshd_config**...

Comment: yes, but my real point was that you just can kill the server, and you don't have to stop the ssh agent, it is the agent that keeps your ssh keys decrypted in his "mind"

Comment: regarding the ssh agent - I didn't know that so thanks)) I'll edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Mac OS X system as with Unix and Linux systems, there is a `/etc/sshd_config` file. In that file you will find the following line:

`#Port 22`

However, unlike with Linux/Unix systems, removing the `#`, which makes the line into a comment and changing the port to the port you wish to use and then restarting the SSH daemon won't cause the system to listen on the port you selected; it will continue to listen on the standard port, 22.

You can get the system to listen on the nonstandard port, however, by editing the `ssh.plist` file as noted in replies to the Server Fault posting [How to change sshd port on Mac OS X?](https://serverfault.com/questions/18761/how-to-change-sshd-port-on-mac-os-x) E.g.:

`sudo vi /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`

In that file look for the following section:

```
<dict>
        <key>Listeners</key>
        <dict>
                <key>SockServiceName</key>
                <string>ssh</string>
```

Replace `ssh` in `<string>ssh</string>`with the port you wish to use e.g., `<string>2222</string>`. Then restart the SSH daemon using the two commands below:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

Then , if you issue a netstat command, such as the following, you should see the system listening on the nonstandard port.

```
$ netstat -an | grep 2222
tcp6       0      0  *.2222                 *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  *.2222                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

Note: it might be better to not use a [well-known port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports) number, which may lead to later confusion. I.e., it might be better to use a port greater than 1024 rather than reassign one used for a standard service such as [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol). FTP, not [telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet), uses port 21. FTP uses it for its command port. Telnet uses port 23.

Comment: You are right - ftp -not telnet... my fault, but it doesn't make a difference... No matter which port I specify in **/etc/sshd_config**, when I restart the server it is still running on 22... wtf????

Comment: @Andrew, when I edited `/etc/sshd_config` on an OS X 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion) system, I got the same results as you. I found that I had to edit `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`, instead. I've corrected the answer I posted previously.

Comment: thanx dude! accepted! In fact this is the only way to do it in OS X... changing the **/etc/sshd_config** doesn't make any changes... let's say if you do 2222 in **.plist** and 21 in **sshd_config** server will start on 2222.

Comment: it does not work anymore with MacOs Catalina, the file `ssh.plist` is protected and disabling `csrutil` does not help anymore.

Answer (score 0):

@barlop was very close. There are two places you have to make this modification. One is for the ssh client and one is for the ssh daemon (i.e. server).

The ssh client is in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and the ssh daemon is in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

You then restart ssh using `sudo service ssh restart`.

My nmap now reports:

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000032s latency).
PORT   STATE  SERVICE VERSION
21/tcp open   ssh     (protocol 2.0)
22/tcp closed ssh
```

I can now ssh to my own machine via port 21:

```
$ telnet 10.64.10.200 21
Trying 10.64.10.200...
Connected to 10.64.10.200.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
```

Port 21 is closed:

```
$ telnet 10.64.10.200 22
Trying 10.64.10.200...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Comment: Are you modifying the SSH client on the system on which you are running the SSH server? If so, it won't help you one bit if you try to establish an SSH connection from some other system where the SSH client will expect to use the standard port of 22. The usual way to connect to an SSH server listening on a non-standard port is to specify the port on the command line with the `-p` option. E.g., `ssh -p 2222 jdoe@example.com` if the server was listening on the non-standard port of 2222. Then, if you need to connect to another SSH server listening on the standard port, you just omit the `-p`.

Comment: @moonpoint, you are right and that's exactly what I was planning to do.

Comment: changing the client on the same machine which starts the server doesn't make sense. It may make sense to change it on the client machine, but I was just planning to specify port on a client side through a command line as moonpoint says... like `ssh -p 21` or another port... The problem is that even modifying **/etc/sshd_config** and restarting the ssh server does not start ssh on custom port. It just runs on the same default port 22 - no matter what port I'm specifying in  **/etc/sshd_config**

Comment: @NZD, also `service` command is absent in OS X 10.10.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mac OS X. The `service` command is Linux specific (Ubuntu actually) but on a Linux/Unix machine `/etc/init.d/ssh restart` does the same.